# Azure pipeline set displayname of task based on condition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In the build pipeline I have a job with a powershell script setting the applicatiuon name based on a variable like this:

```
$applicationName = If ('$(configuration)' -eq 'Release') { 'Appname' } Else { 'Appname-Test' }
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=applicationName]$applicationName"
```

I try to set the display name of the `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` variable to the variable like this:

```
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1        
    displayName: $[variables.applicationName] #  runtime variable
```

But this literally displays `$[variables.applicationName]` instead of the variable value. How can I change the displayname of a task based on a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't appear that this is currently possible.  In both issues I found, they described this as a feature request.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/2327

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/45

Comment: Based on the example in the other answer, this might have been completed.  Might not be available in the on-premise version I was looking at.  Whenever you change the "answer" I'll delete this one.

Answer (score 12):

You can just use the variable in this way: $(variableName). for example:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  test: "SomeValue"

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Write-Host "Hello World"'
  displayName: "The variable $(test)"
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: oh nice, I'll check tomorrow. I guess in my attempts I used single quotes instead of double enquotation

Comment: It does only work with a `variables` declaration, but when I try to overwrite the value (for example "SomeValue" to  "AnotherValue") the old value gets displayed

Comment: How do you overwrite the value?

Comment: I have 2 jobs in my pipeline. In the first job I use powershell to overwrite the variable - see the code included in my question. Then I try to use this overwritten value as displayname in the second job.

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann it because the steps name evaluated when the pipeline starts to run, so even you change the variable value and couldn't affect the step name.

Comment: not working when referencing a variable in the `displayName` from a template file .  any ideas on that situation?

Comment: This also works for template task parameters. e.g. `displayName: 'Building ${{parameters.published_zip_file_name}}'` The parameter is defined inside the template file

Answer (score 4):

I assume `${{..}}` is the way to go. You know the `configuration` at compile time, so you can create the app name at compile time.

```
variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables.configuration, 'Release') }}:
    applicationName: 'Appname'
  ${{ if ne(variables.configuration, 'Release') }}:
    applicationName: 'Appname-Test'
```

```
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1        
    displayName: ${{ variables.applicationName }}
```

Comment: Please check my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the displayName using conditional template below

```yaml
 - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
   ${{ if eq(variables.configuration, 'Release') }}:      
     displayName: Appname
   ${{ else }}:
     displayName: Appname-Test
```