# azure devops , displayname with variable

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline

```
- job: Display_Version
  displayName: Update version $(Number_Version) 
  steps: 
  ....
```

I am trying to display a variable which is the variables of the pipeline, and it does not display it ...
Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure pipeline set displayname of task based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62896477/azure-pipeline-set-displayname-of-task-based-on-condition)

Comment: no because the variable is set manually before the run pipeline by dev

Comment: can you share with us, who you set value of the variable `$(Number_Version)`?

Answer (score 19):

To use the pipeline-level variable in the **`displayName`** of a job or a stage, you should use the expression '**`${{ variables.varName }}`**'. Because the **`displayName`** of jobs and stages are set at compile time.

The expression '**`${{ variables.varName }}`**' is called template expression which can be used to get the value of variable at compile time, before runtime starts.

The macro syntax '**`$(varName)`**' can get the variable value during runtime before a task runs. So, you can use it in the **`displayName`** and the input of a task.

For more details, you can see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax).

Below is an example as reference.

- **azure-pipelines.yml**

  ```yaml
  variables:
    Number_Version: 1.1.0

  jobs:
  - job: Display_Version
    displayName: 'Job Name - Update version ${{ variables.Number_Version }}'
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Task Name - Update version $(Number_Version)'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo "Input of task - Update version $(Number_Version)"
  ```
- **Result**

  [image]

Comment: not work error ...

Comment: The task display name requires that the variable is available at compile time, so it cannot be used if the variable is a result of a previous task.

Comment: Any idea how one can use variables from a variable template?